# How to move app to the background and open another one on the same driver in selenium

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I'm trying to run automation test on ios, using selenium & appium in java.

I have 2 apps:
First will be referred to as "login app".
Second will be referred to as "open with app".

My scenario is starting with login to the first app, then i'm using driver.quit to close the app (while trying to remain logged in).
Then open the second app, open using it to open the first app.

My main problem is that once using driver.quit -> instead of remaining logged in on the first app, 
it causes my user to log out - navigating my user to login page.

Note: 
I saw on appium site : "Support for automating multiple apps in one session: No" - in iOS
So that's why i'm closing my driver and reopen it - when open the second app.

Edit:
To simplify the question, my problem can also be described as follows - I open the 1st app and click a button in that app that triggers the opening of a 2nd app.
When I try to click a button in the 2nd app, appium gets stuck.
Meaning, the element can be found but the automation test does not return from the click function.

Any assistance would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the Appium server using the "--no-reset" argument. So, from the command line:

```
appium --no-reset
```

You can also set this in the Appium desktop application in the "iOS Settings".